# can't select a color profile to be applied to my laptop screen

Tags: color-management

My laptop has a Full HD display but the default hue, contrast, saturation etc.  settings on it are so bad that I needed to adjust them in Windows 10 to be much more pleasant. So I used tools like Intel HD Graphics and Windows Color Correction application and I am able to adjust the display settings of my laptop monitor in Windows 10.

However, I don't know how to do that in Ubuntu 18.04. In Settings>Devices>Color there's no option but just a switch for "Laptop Screen" On / Off, so that won't help.

Any tips on how to perform this operation?